# java JDialog draw called double

Tags: java, jdialog

I've got a problem which makes me go crazy. I call a Method via this line of code:

```
private void btnGetFolderMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    MessageController.showAlert(AlertBox.AlertType.OK);
}
```

and this method is called:

```
public class MessageController {
public static void showAlert(AlertBox.AlertType alertType) {
    AlertBox alertBox = new AlertBox("Test12345678910dfkjsdgmdgbu<xdfg<bdxgj ghfhftz rgdx", alertType);
    alertBox.getRootPane().setOpaque(false);
    //alertBox.getContentPane ().setBackground (new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    //alertBox.setBackground (new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    alertBox.setVisible(true);

//      BDialog dialog = new BDialog();
//      dialog.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("Nach Box");
    //alertBox.invalidate();
}
}
```

And here is my JDialog class:

```
public class AlertBox extends JDialog {
private ImageIcon downSide = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AlertBox/Down_Side.png"));
private ImageIcon leftDownCorner = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AlertBox/Left_Down_Corner.png"));
private ImageIcon leftSide = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AlertBox/Left_Side.png"));
private ImageIcon leftUpCorner = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AlertBox/Left_Up_Corner.png"));
private ImageIcon rightDownCorner = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AlertBox/Right_Down_Corner.png"));
private ImageIcon rightSide = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AlertBox/Right_Side.png"));
private ImageIcon rightUpCorner = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AlertBox/Right_Up_Corner.png"));
private ImageIcon upSide = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/AlertBox/Up_Side.png"));

private String text;

private Rectangle2D fontSize;

private Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13);

private ImagedButton btnOK;

public enum AlertType{
    OK,
    Warning,
    Error
}

private AlertType alertType;

public AlertBox(String text, AlertType alertType){

    // Set JDialog properties
    super(new JFrame(), true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    this.text = text;
    this.alertType = alertType;

    btnOK = new ImagedButton("OK");
    btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button Clicked");
            exitAlertBox();
        }
    });
    //this.add(btnOK);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // Create Graphics2D Object
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    // Get the Size
    fontSize = StringMetrics.getBounds(g2d, font, text);

    // set the fontSize
    int width = (int) fontSize.getWidth() + 5 + leftSide.getIconWidth() + 5 + rightSide.getIconWidth();
    int height = leftUpCorner.getIconHeight() + 5 + (int)fontSize.getHeight() + 5 + btnOK.getHeight() + 5 + leftDownCorner.getIconHeight();
    this.setSize(width, height);

    //this.replaceButton(width, height);

    // Draw Left Upper Corner
    System.out.println(leftDownCorner.getIconWidth() + " ; " + leftDownCorner.getIconHeight());
    g.drawImage(leftUpCorner.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Buttons/Button_Down.png")).getImage(), 21, 20, this);

    // Draw Upper Side
    //g.drawImage(upSide.getImage(), leftUpCorner.getIconWidth(), 0, 5 + (int) fontSize.getWidth() + 5, upSide.getIconHeight(), this);

    // Draw Right Upper Corner
    //g.drawImage(rightUpCorner.getImage(), this.getWidth() - rightUpCorner.getIconWidth(), 0, this);

    // Draw Left Side
    //g.drawImage(leftSide.getImage(), 0, leftUpCorner.getIconHeight(), leftSide.getIconWidth(), 5 + (int)fontSize.getHeight() + 5, this);

    // Draw Right Side
    //g.drawImage(rightSide.getImage(), width - rightSide.getIconWidth(), rightUpCorner.getIconHeight(), rightSide.getIconWidth(), 5 + upSide.getIconHeight() + 5, this);

    // Draw Left Downer Corner
    //g.drawImage(leftDownCorner.getImage(), 0, height - leftDownCorner.getIconHeight(), this);

    // Draw Right Downer Corner
    //g.drawImage(rightDownCorner.getImage(), this.getWidth() - rightUpCorner.getIconWidth(), height - rightDownCorner.getIconHeight(), this);

    // Draw Downer Side
    //g.drawImage(downSide.getImage(), leftDownCorner.getIconWidth(), height - downSide.getIconHeight(), 5 + (int) fontSize.getWidth() + 5, downSide.getIconHeight(), this);



    // Draw the text
    //g2d.drawString(text, 10, 10);
    //g2d.drawString(text, leftUpCorner.getIconWidth() + 5, (int)fontSize.getHeight() + 8);


    if (this.alertType == AlertType.OK){

    }
}

private void replaceButton(int width, int height){
    // paint OK-Button
    int testWidth = width - (btnOK.getWidth() / 2);
    int testHeight = height - btnOK.getHeight() - 5;

    btnOK.setBounds(testWidth, testHeight, btnOK.getWidth(), btnOK.getHeight());
}

private void exitAlertBox(){
    this.dispose();
}
}
```

The problem is, that the window should (at this version of code) display 2 Images. Well it does.. sometimes.. But most of the runs it doesn't.

[image: not showing]

[image: showing]

When I debug my code, it seems like the 'paint' Method is called twice, but i don't find the line where this happens.

Did i do anything wrong?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Don't override paint of top level containers like JDialog, instead, use a custom component extending from something like JPanel and override its paintComponent method, making sure you call super.paintComponent before you perform any custom painting, then add this panel to your dialog

Comment: Why's it not working? JDialog has a JRootPane and content pane ontop of it, which can be painted independently of its parent, which would "paint" over what you did in the paint method, hence the previous suggestion

Comment: Alright, i solved with your answer. I created a JPanel. Thanks ^^